# Custom TextView features using android:background tag more than once

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem with the `android:background` tag, which I am only able to use once, while I need more than once feature for my `TextView`s. More details below:

I got 3 `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/info" android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tour1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tour \n disponibili  \n 21"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tour2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tour1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tour \n prenotabili  \n 16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tour3" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tour2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tour \n preferiti  \n 3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

shown here:

[image]

The `TextView` border is obtained with this file, `back.xml`, included in `res/drawable` folder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <!--<solid android:color="#ffffff" />-->
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

Since I am already using the background tag to input the `back.xml` file and create a rectangular border for the `TextView`s, I don't know how to use it for my other needs, which are:

- get a border for the TextView WITH also round corners
- get an icon as background of the TextView as shown here: [image: here]

As far as I know I can only do this with the tag `background`, which is already used to get the `back.xml` drawable.

How can I fulfill my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided was most probably achieved with the "drawableTop" attribute. Like you said, each attribute can only be used once so if you want to use different images and have them be part of the background, you will need different background resources for each view.

For the rounded corner, add a  tag in your back.xml file below the  tag and define the radius using "android:radius".

To create a selector which also reacts to state changes (say you want the border to turn red when the view gets pressed) use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ff0000"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Put it in the drawable folder and point the "background" attribute at it.

Comment: how to do the same with the tag `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" ?

Comment: You can write your own selector to define different backgrounds for different states of the view. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList to see how to do it. You will need to define a "drawable" and a combination of "state_*" attributes to make the view react to its state changes.

Comment: could you provide an example, please?